# How to sort a continually growing arraylist?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, sequential

This is the code that I have so far and everything runs fine. 
The thing I'm confused about is how do I compare the new items added to the arraylist? I was looking at the comparator but I don't think it suits this situation? I might be wrong but I can't seem to figure out the logic behind this. I was going to do it manually but then realized that, this is probably not a smart idea. How would I create an insertion sort algorithm? I was going to use the sequential sorting method but I feel like I'm missing something. Can anyone shed some light?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String entry;
        boolean loop = true;

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Simple Sorting Program");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("======================");
        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("At start this list contains: "  + list);    
        System.out.println(""); 

        while(loop = true){

            System.out.print("Enter val (neg to end): ");
            entry = input.next();

            if (entry.charAt(0) !='-'){
                Integer val = Integer.valueOf(entry);
                list.add(val);
                System.out.println("List now contains: " + list);
            }
            else{
                loop = false;
                System.out.println("At end, list contains: "+ list);
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");                 
            }                   
        }
    }
```

Comment: The basic answer would be don't.  Once sorted, you should calculate the location where the next value would need to be inserted and insert it directly.  You can use some kind binary search algorithm to try and calculate the preferable location where the item should be inserted

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29 will calculate the insertion point in a sorted list.

Comment: Why not use a `TreeSet` instead? Do you really need dupes?

Comment: If it needs to be kept sorted while adding to it, sounds like a job for a `Set`

Comment: @BrettOkken using `TreeMap` instead of `TreeSet` will help with duplicates. Elements as keys, element count as value.

Comment: @Everv0id tha would be guava multiset ;) - [TreeMultiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) specifically

Comment: the arraylist should accept duplicates though :c

Comment: @izzystreaks, while the arraylist accepts duplicates, it is not intended to be constantly sorted. For anything more than a trivial number of objects this will be rather expensive. Remember that inserting into the middle of an array list requires "copying" every object over 1 element in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MadProgrammer stated, the best way is to use a search algorithm, notably the binary search algorithm is fairly efficient at O(logN), and then insert the data value in context.

Comment: I used a method similar to it, ended up going sequential but your answer is the closest so for anyone's future reference this is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no requirement to use a List, or to refer to your entries using the element entry number, you could consider replacing your List with a [TreeBag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/TreeBag.html) from apache commons.

This implements the [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface and will internally maintain the elements natural order (in this case Integers) when adding new values. They will be listed in order via Iterator and implicitly via the toString() method when printing the contents.

```
#include org.apache.commons.collections4.bag.TreeBag;

 ...

Collection<Integer> list = new TreeBag<Integer>();

 ...
```

To use this one needs to download the [commons-collections.jar](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi) and include it in the classpath when running the program.